# Custom search by several options send on form not works

Tags: customization, search, users, request-filter

I am using the Advanced Custom Field Plugin to add custom fields for the users profiles and display a list of users in the frontend of site with Simple User Listing Plugin.

I need to filter a list of users by a custom search through some options: city, neighborhood and course university.

See an example of how it is being used in this screenshot:

[See the screenshot of user profile displayed on the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLiLd.png)

I created a form that provides the dropdown fields to allow choice of city, neighborhood and choose one of courses, but filtering does not work.

Instead of search a single user, as what is provided by the plugin, I need to display multiple users based on the search terms.

My question is: How to pass an array of values ​​to search for users and return to the list?

Here's an example of the code that I added to search by the city, the neighborhood and the course, but the search does not work. I do not know much about PHP.

```
if ($_GET["FormOfSearch"]){ // if search form is submitted

if(isset($_GET["nome_of_city"]))
{
  $select_city = $_GET["name_of_city"];
}else{
  $select_city = "";
}

if(isset($_GET['name_of_neighborhood']))
{
  $select_neighborhood = $_GET['name_of_neighborhood'];
}else{
  $select_neighborhood = '';
}

if(isset($_GET['name_of_course'])){
  $select_course = $_GET['name_of_course'];
}else{
  $select_course = '';
}

$list_of_id  = "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE (meta_value = '$select_city') AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE (meta_value= '$select_neighborhood')) AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE (meta_value = '$select_course'))";

// Below, the array provided by plugin, I add the list of ID searched
// Generate the query based on search field
 $args2 = array(
        'include' => '*' . $list_of_id . '*',
        'number' => $number,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => $order
           );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put value of keys and check results.(use `get_users` function to query users)

```
$args=array(
    'relation'=>'AND'
);
if(isset($_GET["nome_of_city"])){
    $arg[]=array(
            'key' => 'your_key_name_1',
            'value' => $_GET["nome_of_city"]
        );
}
if(isset($_GET['name_of_neighborhood'])){
    $arg[]=array(
        'key' => 'your_key_name_2',
        'value'=>$_GET['name_of_neighborhood'],
        'compare'=>'IN'
        );
}
if(isset($_GET['name_of_course'])){
    $arg[]=array(
        'key' => 'your_key_name_3',
        'value'=> $_GET['name_of_course'],
        'compare'=>'IN'
        );
}
$users=get_users($args);
 foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
    }
```

**Important Link**:

[get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Answer (score 0):

Ravs Hello, thanks for the reply and the help. Sorry for the delay in responding.

Well, I did exactly as you stated above, but I can not spend my arrays to function of plugin according to search.

See: I created a function my_arrays that returns three arrays, each one will be created if the user select an option select.

So I return the array to the function of plugin: `return array_merge( $args3, $args4, $args5 )`, Using a filter: `add_filter('sul_user_query_args', 'my_arrays', 10, 3);`

Being that, 'sul_user_query_args' is the filter of plugin, see how is defined in the plugin:

`$args = apply_filters( 'sul_user_query_args', array_merge( $args1, $args2 ) );`

The paging, the role and the total users per page are defined in $ args1 and after adding my filter the rules of $args1 does not work.

The issue is: How to apply my arrays to the filter?

I appreciate any help.